# How can I combine grep with file and extra regex

Tags: linux, grep, regular-expression

I have a file of strings in each line.

For example:

```
AAAAA   
BBBBB   
CCCCC  
etc
```

I want to check each string one by one whether it exists in a series of files in a specific directory.

I know that I can do: `grep -f filename` to do the search. But what I need is to use one more regular expression per line to get more specific results. The file with the strings is big and changes often so it does not make sense to modify each line to add an expression.

So what I need is to combine the `grep -f filename` to loop over each line of the file (and grep for it in the files) but add some more conditions. E.g. that `AAAAA` exists **and** `[0-9]{1,3}$` exists as well in the same line.

Comment: Is the additional condition different for each line of the file?

Comment: @JosephR.:No.The same condition for all lines of the file.But the file's contents are changing constantly and are a lot so I need to search for these contents.But the condition `X` would be the same for all lines

Answer (score 3):

You can do this stepwise with `grep` and a pipeline

```
grep -f your_file list_of_files|grep -E extra_condition
```

or

```
while read line; do
    grep -E -e "$line" -e extra_condition list_of_files
done < your_file
```

In both cases, the `-E` switch is needed if you're going to use a pattern of the form `[0-9]{1,3}$` (i.e. containing numerical quantifiers).

**Edit**

Thanks to Drav Sloan's comment, we know that the second version (the `while` loop), not only can be reduced to

```
grep -E -e "extra_condition" -f your_file list_of_files
```

but that it actually looks for one pattern *or* the other not one pattern *and* the other. You should stick with the first form.

Comment: So this passes one line of the file at a time to `grep -E`? So something like: `grep -f filename ./*.csv |grep -E regex`?

Comment: @Jim Basically, yes.

Comment: Sorry for the lamen question.The second script is exactly as you post it? I.e. redirect my file to `done`?

Comment: @Jim Yes, the redirection actually affects the `read` call which should be expecting input on stdin and you make it read from the file instead.

Comment: @Jim To clarify the whole `while` loop is a [compound command](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/CompoundCommands) so you're redirecting stdin of the whole loop from the pattern file.

Comment: you can reduce the `while` loop version to `grep -E "extra_condition" -f your_file list_of_files`. Note this has the effect of `OR` rather than `AND` like the first example.

Comment: @Jim See updated answer. Thanks #DravSloan.

Answer (score 1):

Just to show an altnerative way using `awk` and `grep`.

#### Sample Data

```
$ cat patterns.txt 
AAAA
BBBB
CCCC
DDDD
EEEE

$ cat sample.txt 
AAAA 1
AAAA 2
AAAA 3
AAAA 4
DDDD 1
DDDD 2
YYYY 1
YYYY 2
```

#### Examples

*awk #1:*

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0]; next}($1 in a)' patterns.txt sample.txt | grep -E "[0-9]{1,3}$"
AAAA 1
AAAA 2
AAAA 3
AAAA 4
DDDD 1
DDDD 2
```

This will most likely need to be adjusted but gives you a hint as to how to do it.

*awk #2:*

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0];next};{for (i in a){if (match($0,i)) print}}' patterns.txt sample.txt | grep -E "[0-9]{1,3}$"
AAAA 1
AAAA 2
AAAA 3
AAAA 4
DDDD 1
DDDD 2
```

This one is more flexible, it can handle the pattern strings being anywhere within the line of the sample data.